# Third Party Dot Net Core Application works fine when started from cmd prmpt on local machine. But fails when started from remote machine via WebApi

Tags: c#, iis, .net-core, webapi, hl7-fhir

I am using the Vonk Identity Server as Token Server (https://github.com/FirelyTeam/Vonk.IdentityServer.Test)

Its a dotnet core 3.1 application. It works fine on the server machine when I start it from command prompt with proper privileges using below command:
dotnet .\Vonk.IdentityServer.Test.dll
Doing this, will make the app available at http://localhost:5100/
And also I could see the process in the task manager
Further, I can also get Token using Postman.

Now my requirement is to do the same from a client machine using C# code. So I decided to leverage an existing Web API (hosted on IIS) which can start a process using Start.Process c# API.
However, with this approach, I am able to start the process fine. But the end point is not responding.

NOTE:

1. I have already checked the user privileges.
2. The below scenario works fine if I introduce another exe in between to invoke the Dot Net Core App as below:
   client -> Web API-> Intermediate C# Exe -> Invokes DotNet Core App via Start.Process

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "So I decided to leverage an existing Web API (hosted on IIS) which can start a process using Start.Process c# API" is never the right approach. An ASP.NET Core app should be properly deployed, and the vendor already talked about that in documentation, https://docs.fire.ly/projects/Firely-Server/en/latest/deployment/reverseProxy/reverseProxy.html

Comment: Thanks Lex. I completely agree to that. But existing implementation already starts the App as console. I guess I need to change all of that. Thanks for showing the way. Appreciate it.

Comment: Deploy the application on IIS is the easiest way so that it can keep running. But if you insist on your way, I want to know what you have checked about user privileges? how the api start the process and how can you make sure the process is used to run core application?